# TQDM bar doesnt increase

Tags: python-3.x, tqdm

I was making a telethon bot to download videos. Then I decided to display the progress on my terminal. Telethon download provides a progress_callback so I was able to get current and total values. Then I used them on tqdm. The values after the bar increased but the percentage and the bar stayed at zero.

This is my code:

```
async def progress(current, total): 

         downloaded = current/1024 

         full_size = total/1024 

         global bar 

         update_var = (downloaded/1024)-bar.n 

         bar.update(update_var) 

         progresss = f'{downloaded/1024:.2f}/{full_size/1024:.2f}' 

         await client.edit_message(msg, f'Downloading video... {progresss}')

This is the progress callback function. 

I set up tqdm like this

    global bar 

     bar = tqdm(total=file_size, unit_scale=True, desc="Download progress")
```

The output is:
Download progress:   0%| | 1.38/2.21M [00:10<3257:30:04

As you see, the percentage and the bar size didn't increase when the values are increasing. Am I doing anything wrong? Please help me I'm new to tqdm.
I'm using python 3.10.6

Comment: It cannot be removed. It is there to inform telegram user of the progress. The tqdm bar is for me to check the usages. Edit: It has nothing to do with tqdm

Answer (score 1):

I was doing stuff on the code and I came across what was wrong. I gave the total size in bits and current variable in mbs. When I opened in tqdm they somehow converted the bits of mbs that's why I didn't notice it yet. Also a big thank you for everyone for trying to help me.